# Error connecting to Oracle from Visual Studio

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio, oracle

I am not able to connect to Oracle using connection string and the correct password. I've tried the same parameters in SQL developer and sqlplus(commandline) and they are working. I even tried changing the password but no use.

Any ideas what might be wrong or where should I start looking?
The exact Oracle error is : 
**invalid username/password password, logon denied** 
and after trying a few times account is getting locked with 
 **the account is locked**

Comment: I want to add that, this error came in an application that has been running for a while now. You could say out of the blue

Comment: Did you try connecting with Toad?

Comment: Is this an 11g database?

Comment: Not toad but sql developer and sqlplus(command line) no its a 10g database

Comment: can you post the exact connect string you're using ?

Comment: Which options and connect string are you giving? And which version of VS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the problem was with cache on the computer. Even though I am giving "server='correctdb'" visual studio was taking "server='olddb'" as input and hence I am not able to connect. Pathetic but that's what happened.

Answer (score 0):

When I've run into this, it has ALWAYS been an issue with my connect string.

What is your connect string?  It should be something like "User Id=[ID]; Password=[PWD]; Data Source=[DB]"

Of course, you'd replace [ID], [PWD] and [DB] as appropriate.

Comment: Yes its like this. I've been using this code from the last 2 years. It worked on friday and now it doesn't :(

Answer (score 0):

Is it just your computer that exhibits the problem, or are others seeing it as well?

Can you test your connection in the ODBC Data Source Administrator? Does that work?

Comment: Just verified, another computer also seeing this problem

Answer (score 0):

Try to install the [Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio](http://www.oracle.com/technology/tech/windows/odpnet/index.html). It's free but you need to register, also free.

Answer (score 0):

You need to [unlock the account](http://www.tiplib.com/103/unlock-oracle-user-account).

(From above referenced site)

```
SQL> ALTER USER username ACCOUNT LOCK;

SQL> ALTER USER username ACCOUNT UNLOCK;
```

Comment: On accounts locked, the error is "Account locked", not bad password.

Comment: Account locking isn't related to the user's password - its different.  Its like if sysadmin locks your linux account, you just can't sign in, until he unlocks it.  Give http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Oracle_database_Security_FAQ a read.